# Jasper Report: Store in variable value of parameter bean property

Tags: java, spring, parameters, jasper-reports

I've a little issue to propose.

I've defined in Spring a bean named EnvParam. I've passed this bean in my report processed by Jasper, using an hashmap of parameters.

In Jasper XML I've mapped my bean with import tag in this way:

```
<import value="Mypath.EnvParam" />
```

After that I want to point my bean properties in GUI elements.

So, I've defined in Jasper some variables in this way:

```
varDummy = $P{EnvParam}.myProperty
```

so in my GUI element I've that link $V{varDummy}.

When I run my application my report doesn't show the correct value of property, setting NULL in my GUI.

But if I put in my GUI object my property $P{EnvParam}.myProperty without using of variable the value will show correctly.

Comment: @Chris: You're right. Sorry for my fault. But can we use question comments for these communications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved my issue, changing the procession time of variable, put the value as "REPORT"

The default the value has set on "NOW" (I think - in italian, version used the value named "ADESSO")